# Google Calendar APIs for Apppointments

Tags: calendar, google-calendar-api

I am building a booking application which requires a calendar for each asset which can be booked for a given time slot. my aim is to assign a calendar to each resource and manage their availability, booking , conflict management.

is this possible? to create unlimited calendar with one account and name each calendar with resource?

how to go about the same?

Thanks
yogesh

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you can create an unlimited calendar with one account. AFAIK, as stated in this [tutorial](http://www.daimto.com/google-calendar-api-with-php-service-account/) it is possible for an "app to allow your users to schedule/reschedule Calendar events using one of your Google calendars, you I don’t need the users to authenticate themselves with Google.What you need to use is the Google Calendar API with a service account."

Try the suggestion in this [forum](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!msg/calendar/gkG8MCgNTxs/En7Y88pB0DAJ), to enable your user to create an event to multiple calendar make your user's email as a value in the [attendees](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/concepts/#events_with_attendees) this will make your authenticated user be able get the events to their own calendar.

You would create your own implementation for managing availability and conflict management.

Hope this helps.